# Is there a way to render an .png image of the webpage and save it to a directory using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm on the final part of writing a CasperJS test script, and I need to render a .png image of the webpage that's been manipulated and save it to a directory of my choosing. Anybody know how I could do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at the API docs http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.capture

Comment: @Prinzhorn, would you please post that as an answer? This looks like an original question that could help future searchers; therefore it should be left open and answered.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand hm, hoogling for "casperjs capture" points to the api docs and the method is even called `capture`. I don't think there's much of a point having this on SO.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, Yeah but "render png web page casperjs" doesn't turn up much, however in few days, this will show up.  Especially for SO users.  Thanks for doing the answer, even though you don't agree :-)

Answer (score 7):

Just look at the docs, the method is called `capture` http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#capture

An example could look like this:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('path/to/image.png');
});
```